# Execute mustache (as ruby script) in cmake execute_process

Tags: ruby, cmake, mustache

I would like to use [mustache](https://github.com/mustache/mustache) as a simple templating engine in cmake for code generation.

I tried to execute it with `execute_process` as follow:

```
execute_process( COMMAND "/path/to/mustache" "<data> <template>" )
```

But it said its not a valid WIN32 application. And indeed, mustache is a ruby script:

```
#!D:/programs/Ruby23/bin/ruby.exe
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'mustache' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0.a"

if ARGV.first

    ...
```

So I tried:

```
execute_process( COMMAMD "/path/to/ruby" "/path/to/mustache --help" )
```

But it don't work either... `No such file or directory -- D:/programs/Ruby23/bin/mustache --help (LoadError)`

How to execute a ruby script in cmake execute_process?

Comment: `But it don't work either...` - It said that ruby is not WIN32 application too? Or what?

Comment: No such file or directory -- D:/programs/Ruby23/bin/mustache --help (LoadError)

Comment: ok. Argumets must be passed as list... ````execute_process( COMMAMD "/path/to/ruby" "/path/to/mustache" "--help" )```` Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> execute_process(COMMAND < cmd1 > [args1...]] ...)

Arguments must be passed as list, not as string.

```
    # path to executables
    set(RUBY_EXECUTABLE D:/programs/Ruby23/bin/ruby.exe CACHE STRING "ruby executable")
    set(MUSTACHE_SCRIPT D:/programs/Ruby23/bin/mustache CACHE STRING "mustache ruby script")

    # function that call mustache
    function(apply_mustache data template result)
        execute_process(
            COMMAND ${RUBY_EXECUTABLE} -E UTF-8 ${MUSTACHE_SCRIPT} ${data} ${template}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE result_t
            )
        set(${result} ${result_t} PARENT_SCOPE)
    endfunction()
```

**bonus**: `-E UTF-8` prevent ruby to mess with utf-8 characters...

Comment: Rather than hard-coding the path to Ruby, I believe it would be better at this point to use the [FindRuby module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindRuby.html), which populates the `Ruby_EXECUTABLE` variable and friends. Aside from being less fragile, it's also portable.